# navbar-brand with img appears underneath toggler-button when collapsed

Tags: bootstrap-4

The brand appears underneath the toggler-button when collapsed, not to the far right as would happen without the addition of an image. How can i get it to appear on the right side (when collapsed)?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="assets/img/google-logo.png" class=""></img>
        </a>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

    </nav>
```

Comment: What is the image size?

Answer (score 0):

The `<ul class="navbar-nav">` had another class next to it, which you removed. If you add in mr-auto, it will fix it. `<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">`

The `.ml-auto` and `.mr-auto` are short for margin-left auto and margin-right auto. Since BS4 uses flexbox, `.ml-auto` will push it to the far right, and `.mr-auto` will push something to the far left.

Of course, this all depends on the size of your logo. When it runs out of room, it will go under the toggle if set up like this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="assets/img/google-logo.png" class="">
    </a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

</nav>
```

Another quick note, don't close your `<img>`, it's a self closing tag. If you really feel the need, you can write it `, but with HTML5 there is no need to do so.